# Concat Results of multiple linq query and sum the values on duplicate

Tags: c#, linq

I have this function that I call on datagridview content change and works.

This is getting a list of names with a value from another column and shows the result in another dgv.

example:

```
group | quantity

chest | 2
back  | 5
legs  | 7
```

The problem is that when I have the same groups in multiple row or dgv I obtain multiple entries in the result datagridview. What I want to do is to sum the values when the same group is entered twice.

So in this case:

```
group | quantity

legs | 2
arms  | 5
legs  | 7
```

Would change in:

```
group | quantity

legs  | 9
arms  | 5
```

I've tried union instead of concat but this delete the duplicate, so if I have 2 entries with same value I lose the duplicate value.

Here the complete function code:

```
private void seriesettimanali()
    {

        // quantity for group of datagridview1
        var Sums = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
          .Where(row => row.Cells[7].Value != null)
        .GroupBy(row => row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()) //inserire colonna gruppo

        .Select(g => new { Group = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value)) });


        // quantity for group of datagridview2
        var Sums2 = dataGridView2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
          .Where(row => row.Cells[7].Value != null)
        .GroupBy(row => row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()) 

        .Select(g => new { Group = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value)) });

        // quantity for group of datagridview3
        var Sums3 = dataGridView3.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
          .Where(row => row.Cells[7].Value != null)
        .GroupBy(row => row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()) 

        .Select(g => new { Group = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value)) });

        // quantity for group of datagridview4
        var Sums4 = dataGridView4.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
          .Where(row => row.Cells[7].Value != null)
        .GroupBy(row => row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()) 

        .Select(g => new { Group = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value)) });

        // quantity for group of datagridview5
        var Sums5 = dataGridView5.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
          .Where(row => row.Cells[7].Value != null)
        .GroupBy(row => row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()) 

        .Select(g => new { Group = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value)) });

        
        var resultSum1 = Sums.Concat(Sums2);
        var resultSum2 = resultSum1.Concat(Sums3);
        var resultSum3 = resultSum2.Concat(Sums4);
        var resultSum4 = resultSum3.Concat(Sums5);

        

        dataGridView6.DataSource = resultSum4.ToList();
    }
```

How can I do?

Comment: You can use `GroupBy` on final result and perform `Sum` again.

Comment: @NikhilPatil Do you have an example of how to do it? I'm new to linq queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I've found the solution:

```
var rs = resultSum4
                .GroupBy(w => w.User)
                .Select(g => new { User = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Sum) });
```